# Bash script cant iterate through folders "-d" not found

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to create a bash script that creates another folder that has the same folder structure as the source folder BUT only copies over actual files that have numbers under `maxSize` at the end of their names.

An example folder structure might look like this

```
Family_Pictures
  Alice
    Alice_Age_15
      picture25.png
      picture2334.png
    Alice_Age_18
      picture0.png
      picture10.png
  Jane
    Jane_Age_90
       picture456.png
```

If I had ran this script with the source directory as Family_Pictures and `maxSize` of 20 I would expect there to be another directory created with the same folders but only 2 pictures in total between them (there would be empty folders)

This is as far as I have gotten per some other Stack Overflow examples however bash is saying that -d is not an existing command.

I am trying to run this script on OSX in terminal.

Here is the script thus far:

```
read -p "What is the max size wanted? " maxSize
read -p "What is the source folder? " sourceFolder
destinationFolder=$sourceFolder' sample '$maxSize
echo $destinationFolder

for D in $sourceFolder; do
        if [-d "${D}"]; then
                echo "${D}"
        fi
done
```

If you see any issues (even if they arent issues causing my current problem) with my script please let me know.

Comment: To solve the immediate issue, you need a space after the `[` and before the `]`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can be really useful to detect things like that.